# Getting error of "Tried to register two views with the same name RNCViewpager

Tags: react-native, uncaught-exception, react-native-tab-view

[image]

Hi, I am getting the error, but i don't know how to solve it.
I think it caused by the conflicts between react-native-tab-view and react-native-pager-view

I tried

- remove node_modules and re-install.
- installed different versions of react-native-pager-view
- added "resolutions" in package.json.

My package.json is

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "filter-obj": "^2.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.1.8",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "payment": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
    "react-native-background-upload": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-checkbox-form": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-checkbox-group": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-credit-card-input-fullpage": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.0.5",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-key-value-storage": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-accessory": "^0.1.12",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-material-buttons": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-no-flicker-image": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-ratings": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-section-list-get-item-layout": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-secure-storage": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.3.3",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.62.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "string": "^3.3.3",
    "tipsi-stripe": "^7.5.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"   },   
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "0.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"   },   
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I clone the repo and modified the ViewManger Name and it worked fine for me you may try it.

past following, to roo dir in package.json and run command `yarn install`

```
"react-native-pager-view": "git://github.com/AtaMuhiuldin/react-native-view-pager.git"
```

it's working for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall react-native-pager-view
```

then

```
npx react-naive run-android
```

i notice that the problem is that when you install the library and this library exist already on some other libraries dependencies

> you can import it without install it again
> check `package-lock.json` you can find it already

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case conflict was between react-native-scrollable-tab-view and react-native-pager-view

To resolve the conflict between react-native-scrollable-tab-view and react-native-pager-view, you can choose to use only one of them in your project.

If you have existing components that rely on react-native-scrollable-tab-view, you can migrate those components to use react-native-pager-view instead

Answer (score 0):

React Native Pager View and @react-native-community/viewpager are libraries with similar functionalities, and it is not advisable to use both simultaneously. You should choose either react-native-pager-view or @react-native-community/viewpager for your project.

However, to ensure compatibility and avoid conflicts, it would be beneficial to consider modifying the library or creating a common library that encompasses the functionalities of both. This approach would allow developers to utilize a unified solution and streamline their implementation process.

Answer (score -2):

Here there is small issue in lib i guess.
If you import like below

```
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';
```

It will not work, but if you try to import like below, it will work.

```
import { PagerView } from 'react-native-pager-view';
```